# Eclipse Plugin - Change Editor Tab color depending of file path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to change the editor tab color depending of the file path.

Because I'm working on an mvc infrastructure, and well, we often get the same file name in 3 different folders.

[image: Liste - Liste - Liste] (Liste is french for List)

And well I was wondering if it is possible to change the tab color? I did not find what I wanted on Google + Eclipse API, So here I am, posting.

Anyway, help on this would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, because there is no way to change the color of `CTabItem`. You can however change the font of the `CTabItem` or the icon. You need to create custom `MultiPageEditorPart` and override the `addPage()` methods and handle the creation of `CTabItems`